# Display product_brand with get_the_terms function

Tags: php

I am stuck trying to display a product brand in wp-admin column.
This is my code and I get an array, instead of a value, should I use a different function?
I've also tried with $term->name but no luck

thanks

```
case 'product_brand' :
            $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'product-brand' );
            if( !empty( $terms ) ){
                echo $terms ;
            }
            else{
                echo 0;
            }
            break;
```

Comment: solved using this `case 'product_brand' :
   $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'product-brand' );
   if( !empty( $terms ) ){
    foreach($terms as $term) {
          echo $term->name;
      };
   }
   else{
    echo 0;
   }
   break;`

Comment: Please post solution you found as an answer so that question doesn't haunt site as unanswered. :)